# WPF DataGrid shows no data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

this is the constructor of the UserControl which includes DataGrid Element.

```
public Results(List<CartItem> Items)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Items.DataContext = Items;
    }
```

and this is the XAML of the DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="Items" IsReadOnly="True" MinHeight="300">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource styleCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Abone No" Binding="{Binding SubscriberNo}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adı Soyadı" Binding="{Binding SubscriberName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fatura Tutarı" Binding="{Binding _Amount, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Son Ödeme Tarihi" Binding="{Binding _Deadline, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I double checked for DataContext object of the DataGrid is properly populated. But No data being shown in DataGrid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generally, there is an ItemSource="{Binding element}"  tag in the datagrids !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have set the DataContext of your Grid. You also have to set the ItemsSource of your Datagrid like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```